# Why t is referencing to index of argv[3] what does the mean of [-1] Thanks

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(char**);

int main()
{
    char *argv[] = { "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl" };
    f(argv);
    return 0;
}

void f(char **p)
{
    char *t;
    t = (p += sizeof(int))[-1];
    printf("%sn", t);
}
```

`t = (p += sizeof(int))[-1];` how does it reference to index three of `argv` I am confuse due to `[-1]`

Comment: `sizeof(int)=4`, so t[0] points to argv[4]. Then you access to index t[-1], which is pointing to argv[3]

Comment: Where did you find this code? Are there no documentation from where you got it? Code like this is really generally discouraged for common code that needs to be read, understood or maintained.

Comment: For the "logic" of this expression, the basic rule is that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i` the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. From this we can derive that `p + i` is a a pointer to the i:th element (effectively `&p[i]`). And as a pointer, we can then add an index to get a third pointer that can be dereferenced to get a value. From all of this we have either `*((p + sizeof(int)) - 1)` or `(&p[sizeof(int)])[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's a weird line it does exactly that, since the size of `int` is 4 normally, you should note that this may not work in all machines, since in some, `int` may not be 4 bytes in size.

Having `argv[4]` is the same as `*(argv + 4)` since `p` = `argv`, having `(p + sizeof(int)) - [1]` is the same as having `(argv + sizeof(int)) - [1]` or `argv + sizeof(int) - 1`,  so `*(argv + 4 - 1)`, so `*(argv + 3)` or `argv[3]`. .

Comment: There is no need to point out what a comment has already clarified in an answer

Comment: @EUS Except comments aren't for answering questions.

Comment: @EUS, what are you doing? Comments are for clarifying questions, not to answer questions, read the rules.

Comment: The answer should go into answer. Yet, this one, could be greatly improved.

Comment: @EugeneSh., you can help me do it

Comment: Explain what `p+=` does. Explain what `[-1]` does, I think it will make it much clearer

Comment: @EUS Yes, there is absolutely a need to do precisely that, and it is encouraged.

Comment: So @EugeneSh., you think it's clear? I hope I'm not confusing the OP more.

Comment: I think it is much better. Other opinions might exist though :)

Comment: @EugeneSh., thanks for the feedback, I remember that  when I was learning C, pointers were somewhat confusing, so I don't want to delay others learning process.

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof(int)` in your case is 4

`p += 4;` - `p` is referencing the 5th element (the one with index 4) of the passed array

`t = p[-1]` t is referencing the 4th element of the passed array (index == 3)

PS 
`t = (p += 4);` is an equivalent to:

```
p+=4;
t = p;
```

Comment: DV ? Any explanation